# Converting two lists into dictionary error

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hi I tried to convert two lists into a dictionary, it worked before.. However, after cleaning the lists data, when I try to convert them into a dictionary, the lists become 'NoneType' and gives me error 'object of type 'NoneType' has no len()'. The lists are fine after data cleaning, they just become nonetype when I try to make them into a dictionary.

I've tried below two ways, giving me same error message

```
SS_DIC = dict(zip(SPACE_3, SYMBAL))
```

and

```
SS_DIC = dict()
for i in range(len(SPACE_3)):
    SS_DIC[SPACE_3[i]] = SYMBAL[i]
```

the lists look like these:

```
SPACE_3
['projects aborad',
'projects abraod',
'rustic pathways',
'physical therapy']

SYMBAL
['projects-aborad',
'projects-abraod',
'rustic-pathways',
'physical-therapy']
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow.
It looks like you have identified your problem as being at the 'cleaning' stage. Show some of your data.

Comment: First shown way works fine for me. Which python version are you using? `python --version`? I make the shown lists by using an additional `=` of course.

Comment: `dict(zip(SPACE_3, SYMBAL))` is the correct way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension to combine two lists into dictionary

```
SPACE_3 = ['projects aborad',
'projects abraod',
'rustic pathways',
'physical therapy']


SYMBAL = ['projects-aborad',
'projects-abraod',
'rustic-pathways',
'physical-therapy']

{key: value for key, value in zip(SPACE_3, SYMBAL)}

{'physical therapy': 'physical-therapy',
 'projects aborad': 'projects-aborad',
 'projects abraod': 'projects-abraod',
 'rustic pathways': 'rustic-pathways'}
```

Comment: Please explain how the error is caused (especially in the first case) and how this code solves the problem.

Comment: code-only answers are considered harmful in the long term, they don't explain anything hence don't help